# Printing Data on the same line with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

How could I print data without a trailing newline in PhantomJS? In nodejs, i used the `process` to write data on the same line.

```
$ process.stdout.write( "Anything..." )
```

But i can find it's equalent in phantomJS. I've tried with PhantomJS `child_process` module but it returns me `undefined` error:

```
var process = require("child_subprocess");
process.stdout.write(" Anything ")
```

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.stdout.write')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it, `system` module is the native phantomjs module for handling `stdin` and `stdout` files. This did the task for me:

```
var system = require("system");
system.stdout.write("Anything...");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here:

```
var process = require("child_process");
```

I do not know, but I think it is not valid statement.
Instead of:

```
var process = require("child_subprocess");
process.stdout.write(" Anything ")
```

You can try only:

```
var process = require("child_process")
process.stdout.write(" Anything ")
```

Comment: There's no such object/variable in PhantomJS environment. It gives me this `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process`

Comment: can you try this: var process = require("child_process"); process.stdout.write(" Anything ")

Comment: Still nothing. I am still getting undefined. There's another native module in phantomjs for this: `system`. I've just got it to work.

Comment: I got this reference here: http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/, but as you know phantomjs in under development now, I think you can go better with nighmare or puppeteer.